# Add an OnLeave function to 140 objects?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I got a windows form with around 140 numericUpDown elements and want all of them to do this:

```
private void numericUpDown_B1_RS_LS_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (numericUpDown_B1_RS_LS.Value < 1 || numericUpDown_B1_RS_LS.Value > 6)
    {
        numericUpDown_B1_RS_LS.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        numericUpDown_B1_RS_LS.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Is there a more comfortable way of doing this than just adding 140 functions to the form manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the same method for all NUDs on your form this will do it:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
        if (ctl.GetType() == typeof(NumericUpDown) ) ctl.Leave += numericUpDown_Leave;

}


private void numericUpDown_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NumericUpDown NumericUD =  (NumericUpDown) sender ;
        if (NumericUD.Value < 1 || NumericUD.Value > 6)
        {
            NumericUD.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            NumericUD.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
```

You can just as easily iterate over the Controls collection of another container, say a Panel or a GroupBox if the NUDs are not directly sitting on the Form. And if some NUDs should be excepted from that behaviour you could mark them in some way, maybe in their Tag or Name and check for that before adding their handlers ..

Comment: working, besides the if-clauses needs to be: ctl.GetType() == typeof(NumericUpDown)

Comment: ah, right, sorry! I wonder why I always miss that and why it didn't show up the compiler an hour ago - it does now, of course..  ;-)  I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not write multiple functions for same code. Instead you can create just one function and assign it to the event method of your numericUpDown element i.e. "UpDown" event.

So whenever any of the element's "UpDown" event will fire, your same function will be executed. And as far as you want to write different methods for different elements, then consider that in your method

```
Method(object sender, EventArguments e)
```

sender is the actual sender object of your updownElement type, and that code will be executed for that particular object only.

You can take for loop to iterate your all 140 elements and assign this function to the "UpDown" element.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could write a static method to handle the adding of event handler recursively, something like:

```
    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
         AddHandleNumericUpdownLeave(this);
    }

    public static void AddHandleNumericUpdownLeave(Control theContrl)
    {
        if (theContrl.Controls != null && theContrl.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Control cControl in theContrl.Controls)
            {
                AddHandleNumericUpdownLeave(cControl);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NumericUpDown nudCtrl = theContrl as NumericUpDown;
            if (nudCtrl != null)
            {
                nudCtrl.Leave += (object senderT, EventArgs eT) =>
                {
                    var tmpCtrl = senderT as NumericUpDown;
                    if (tmpCtrl != null)
                    {
                        if (tmpCtrl.Value < 1 || tmpCtrl.Value > 6)
                        {
                            tmpCtrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tmpCtrl.BackColor = Color.White;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but this might be costly if you have too many controls in a form...